# Construct two functions based on big O constraint

Tags: functions, continuity, asymptotics

I'm doing an algorithm problem goes like this. 
Construct two functions $f$, $g$ : $\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ satisfying,

1. $f$, $g$ are continuous;
2. $f$, $g$ are monotonically increasing;
3. $f\neq O(g)$ and $g\neq O(f)$.

Now I'm wondering how all of these 3 conditions hold here. Is it possible there are any $f$ and $g$ exist? Thank you!

Comment: Why don't $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=e^x$ satisfy those requirements?

Comment: I'm also thinking about $x$ and $e^x$. But I'm not sure if they work here.

Comment: $x$ is $O(e^x)$-certainly there's $x_0$ and $C$ such that for $x>x_0$ $x\leq Ce^x$. For instance take $x_0=1$ and $C=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Such pairs of functions do exist, but are a bit unusual. If $f\neq O(g)$ then for every $x$ and $C$ there's $y>x$ such that $f(y)> Cg(y)$. In other words $f>Cg$ on an unbounded set. On the other hand we have to have $g>Cf$ on an unbounded set. So $f$ and $g$ have to trade places infinitely often while still increasing, and each must even get an arbitrarily long lead on the other. I claim you can do this with $f$ and $g$ both piecewise linear, $f$ constant on intervals of the form $[2n,2n+1]$ and $g$ constant on the other intervals, i.e. of the form $[2n+1,2n+2]$. Just take the slope of each function on the intervals on which it changes increasing sufficiently fast (e.g. exponential.) I'll leave the details to you, but feel free to ask for more clarification.

Comment: Does it mean I could define $f = x$ on the internal $[2n, 2n+1]$ and $f = x^2$ on $[2n+1, 2n+2]$ and vice-versa on the definition of $g$?

Comment: No, it's not continuous and not monotonically increasing. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I've found another detailed [discusstion](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10548/construct-two-functions-f-and-g-satisfying-f-ne-og-g-ne-of).

Comment: The examples at your link aren't continuous, but if you understand them then it shouldn't be hard to make them continuous. (Just add linear bits connecting the constant bits of the graphs.)